# How to compare column with arrays in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery.

Table `a` keeps values in arrays.
Table `b` has row for each value
I want to have all values from table `b` by id if at least one value not in array from table `a` by the same id

```
WITH a as (SELECT 1 as id, ['123', 'abc', '456', 'qaz', 'uqw'] as value
UNION ALL SELECT 2, ['123', 'wer', 'thg', '10', '200']
UNION ALL SELECT 3, null),
b as (SELECT 1 as id, '123' as value
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'abc'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '456'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'qaz'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'uqw'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '123'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'wer'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '10'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, '200'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'thg'
)
```

What is the best way to make it?

Comment: what is expected output?! show example based on presented input data

Comment: I this case it will be all rows with ids 2 and 3 from table `b`. Because values of id 1 are same  in array from table `a` by id 1

Comment: and why id=3 should be in output? respective array in a is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag)
FROM (
  SELECT b.*, COUNTIF(b.value IS NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY id) flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table_a` a, a.value 
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table_b` b
  USING(id, value)
)
WHERE flag > 0
AND NOT value IS NULL
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  value    
1   2   123  
2   2   wer  
3   2   10
```

In case if by your logic - id=3 should also be in output  - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag)
FROM (
  SELECT b.*, COUNTIF(b.value IS NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY id) flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table_a` a LEFT JOIN a.value 
  FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.table_b` b
  USING(id, value)
)
WHERE flag > 0
AND NOT value IS NULL
```

in this case output is

```
Row id  value    
1   2   123  
2   2   wer  
3   2   10   
4   3   200  
5   3   thg
```

Comment: How to return null when value from table `a` is some array and value from table `b` is null by same id?

Comment: use `AND NOT id IS NULL` instead of `AND NOT value IS NULL`

Comment: Thank you. My English is not well. I missed one detail. I need to get all rows from table `b` if it has any difference in values between tables by same id.

Comment: Thank you for reply