# How to compare column in one table with array from another table in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Just continue from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012854/12472644) for my previous question.

I want to get all values from table `b` (in rows) if  there is any difference between values in arrays from table `a` by same ids

```
WITH a as (SELECT 1 as id, ['123', 'abc', '456', 'qaz', 'uqw'] as value
UNION ALL SELECT 2, ['123', 'wer', 'thg', '10', '200']
UNION ALL SELECT 3, ['200']
UNION ALL SELECT 4, null
UNION ALL SELECT 5, ['140']),
b as (SELECT 1 as id, '123' as value
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'abc'
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, '456'
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'qaz'
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'uqw'
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, '123'
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'wer'
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, '10'
      UNION ALL SELECT 3, null
      UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'wer'
      UNION ALL SELECT 4, '234'
      UNION ALL SELECT 5, '140'
      UNION ALL SELECT 5, '121'

)
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag)
FROM (
  SELECT b.*, COUNTIF(b.value IS NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY id) flag
  FROM a LEFT JOIN a.value 
  FULL OUTER JOIN b
  USING(id, value)
)
WHERE flag > 0
AND NOT id IS NULL
```

It works well for all ids except `5`.
In my case I need to return all values if there is any difference.

In example array with id `5` from table `a` has only one value is '140' while there are two rows with values by id `5` from table `b`. So in this case all values by id `5` from table `b` also must appear in expected output

How need to modify this query to get what I want?

---

### UPDATED

Seems like it works for me. But I can not be sure for 100%

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag)
FROM (
  SELECT b.*, COUNTIF((b.value IS NULL AND a.value IS NOT NULL) OR (b.value IS NOT NULL AND a.value IS NULL)) OVER(PARTITION BY id) flag
  FROM a LEFT JOIN a.value 
  FULL OUTER JOIN b
  USING(id, value)
)
WHERE flag > 0
AND NOT id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM table_b 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM table_a a
  JOIN table_b b USING(id)
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING STRING_AGG(IFNULL(b.value, 'NULL') ORDER BY b.value) !=
    IFNULL(ANY_VALUE((SELECT STRING_AGG(IFNULL(value, 'NULL') ORDER BY value) FROM a.value)), 'NULL')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! I updated this post with another solution. Can you tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: i glanced and looks like it should work - good job adjusting answer on your previous question :o)